# Bibliographic style for Journal of Cleaner Production (Elsevier)

Tags: natbib, elsarticle, bibliographystyle

I am trying to format the reference list of an article to be submitted to the Journal of Cleaner Production. Unfortunately, elsarticle does not seem to have the right style in it. The more close seems to be elsarticle-harv.bst, However, many things are different, for example I need abbreviations for the journal names (but elsarticle does not have abbreviations), there is no dot after the journal name, no doi, etc.
Can I find somewhere the .bst file for this journal? Or I need do to a bst. file using the makebst.tex, procedure which seems a bit obscure to me at the moment. Or maybe there is a simpler solution. Maybe it is better not to use elsarticle at all.
Thanks in advance. Here my MWEB file.

```
\documentclass[review,12pt,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{velchev2014empirical,
  title={Example},
  author={Velchev, Stefan and Kolev, Ivan and Ivanov, Krasimir and Gechevski, Simeon},
  journal={Journal of cleaner production},
  volume={80},
  pages={139--149},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    
\citet{velchev2014empirical}
    
  \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv} 
  \bibliography{\jobname}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using `biblatex` or `natbib`? They are pretty different, could you edit your tags to represent which you are using please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using. You can add `.bib` files following this question: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/273733

Comment: Generally, use the style the journal tells you to use.  If they don't tell you to use anything, pick something that looks close to published articles and leave it at that unless they complain.

Comment: @DaiBowen, they tell me which style to use, but I do not know how to get it.
[link](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/journal-of-cleaner-production/0959-6526/guide-for-authors)

Comment: style as in `\bibliographystyle`. This doesn't really answer the question of how to reproduce the specific journal's style, but I'd definitely try the low-effort approach first and submit using an existing bst before manually formatting a whole bibliography or creating my own bst.

Comment: Perusing the pdf file available in the link you posted, I'd say that the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style would be an excellent choice. FWIW, I do *not* see a requirement to abbreviate journal names. Do make sure, though, to specify `authoryear` as one of the options of the `\documentclass[...]{elsarticle}` command.

Comment: I'd change `journal={Journal of cleaner production},` to `journal={Journal of Cleaner Production},`, though.